# JavaMail getMessages doesn't give new messages

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, pop3

I'm facing a weird problem, trying to use JavaMail on mail.ru, but it doesn't give me new emails. I login, start checking getMessages() every second, send email manually, but getMessages() always returns the same emails that were before I sent anything. In other words, it doesn't give any new emails that are past the time it logged into the mailbox. Did I miss something? Here is the full code:

```
public class MailboxReader
{
    private Store store;
    private Folder inbox;
    public MailboxReader(EmailAcc emailAcc)
    {
        // connect to pop3 inbox
        try {
            Properties properties = System.getProperties();
            Security.addProvider(new com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider());
            properties.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
            properties.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
            properties.setProperty("mail.pop3.port", String.valueOf(emailAcc.pop3port));
            properties.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.port", String.valueOf(emailAcc.pop3port));
            properties.setProperty("mail.pop3.ssl.trust", "*");
            Session session = Session.getInstance(properties);
            store = session.getStore("pop3");
            store.connect(emailAcc.pop3ip, emailAcc.pop3port, emailAcc.username, emailAcc.password);
            inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
            inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

        } catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Message[] getMessages()
    {
        try {
            return inbox.getMessages();
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void close()
    {
        try {
            inbox.close(true);
            store.close();
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I have manually logged into recipient's email account to check whether my email arrives - it does. And also, if I reconnect to mailbox with JavaMail, it also sees it. But it would be stupid to keep reconnecting every second, something else is wrong.

Comment: First, [get rid of the socket factory settings](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes).  You [can't tell which messages are new with pop3](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#newmsgs); try using imap.

Answer (score 0):

**Summary:** Add `folder.getMessageCount()` before executing search.

**Explanation**

I had the same experience with Outlook while using IMAP.
Constantly doing: `folder.search(...)` didn't show new messages arriving. It seemed like the folder needed to be refreshed before making new search.

The same like for TS, if I were closing the connection and opening a new one before launching new `.search(...)` then everything worked as intended.

My solution to "refresh" the folder was to do: `folder.getMessageCount()` before executing `.search(...)` and after that new messages could be seen and retrieved without the need to close and reopen the connection